# How to set the correct type in a reduce function that returns an ES6 Map?

Tags: typescript

I would like to write a reduce function that returns an ES6 Map in Typescipt. Here's a toy example:

```
const myMap = [1,2,1,3,3,4,1,5].reduce((acc:any, el:number) => {
    if (!acc.has(el)) acc.set(el, [])
    acc.get(el).push(el)
    return acc
}, new Map() as Map<number, number[]>)
```

The output of `myMap` is:

```
Map (5) {
  1 => [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  2 => [ 2 ],
  3 => [ 3, 3 ],
  4 => [ 4 ],
  5 => [ 5 ]
}
```

What I'm having trouble understanding is how I can define the correct type to `acc` in the reduce function. I don't want to use a type of `any`. What is the best way to set the type of a reduce function that return a `Map`?

Comment: `new Map() as Map<String, number[]>` <--- you already typed you accumulator. It probably should be not `String`, but `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
const myMap = [1,2,1,3,3,4,1,5].reduce((acc: Map<number, number[]>, el:number) => {
    if (!acc.has(el)) acc.set(el, [])
    acc.get(el).push(el)
    return acc
}, new Map<number, number[]>())
```

Since your input array contains numbers, I suggest you use numbers for your keys in your `Map` as well. If you really need `String` there, you could change `number` to `String` and call `toString()` on your elements before manipulating them.

Answer (score 0):

The types of the parameters can be inferred, so I would just leave them unspecified - if you have no implicit any enabled in your tsconfig it should still build without error, which proves that they are correctly inferred